# Stub function calls inside a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

I'm writing a web app using `nodejs`. I have some utils functions which I export and test separately. There is another function though, that calls some of those utils functions that I would like to stub (using `sinon`).
From what I've seen so far, I can only stub methods on objects, so how should I design my utilities functions so I can test all of them?

```
function util1() {
    ...
}

function util2() {
    ...
}

function util3() {
    ...
    util1();
    ...
    util2();
}

export {
    util1,
    util2,
    util3
}
```

Inside `util3` I want to mock (or stub) the calls for `util1` and `util2`.

Comment: Can you add some more to the question so its more clear? I cannot see a usecase yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could put util1 and util2 in a separate module and then use some solution or existing module like `mock-require` https://github.com/boblauer/mock-require.

But perhaps the simplest solution is actually to change your design to use objects.  Then you could create your object with stubs and feed it into an object with a util3 method.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to:

```
function util3() {
    ...
    moddule.exports.util1();
    ...
    module.exports.util2();
}
```

The second way is to wrap everything in a map

```
var self = module.exports = {
    util3 : function() { 
       self.util2();
    },
    util2 : function() { },
..}
```